# Crazy behavior when using compiler optimization

Tags: compiler-optimization

Execution of the following code runs to "!!!" when the compiler is optimized:

```
int test()
{
  volatile uint32_t flag = 0; /* volatile doesnt matter */

  flag = 3;
  if (flag == 0 ) 
  {
      return 0; // !!!
  }
  else
  {
      return 1;
  }
}
```

Compiler: IAR Studio C compiler; Platform: SAM4C microcontroller; medium level optimization

Of course, this is already a code, where the original problem has been boiled down.

I cannot understand what the compiler is doing here ...

On the other hand, this works as expected:

```
int test()
{
  volatile uint32_t flag = 0; /* volatile doesnt matter */
  int result = 0;

  flag = 3;
  if (flag == 0 ) 
  {
      result = 0; 
  }
  else
  {
      result = 1; // !!!
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks mysterious, are there any clues in the asm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some more time and observed, that the function indeed returns 1, although the debugger stops at the line with "return 0;".

The problem I ran into was rather related to an uninitialized variable (outside the function), which is not automatically set to zero during optimization.

Apart from the strange behavior in the debugger, the function is correct. Unfortunately, the observation resulted in a misinterpretation.